# Generic wildcards in java. Compile error.

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have the following java code: `Box<? extends Integer> i = new Box<Integer>(); i.set(10);`. Why does it not compile?

Comment: Why not just `Box<Integer> i = new Box<Integer>();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a `Box<? extends Integer>` can be a `Box<SomeSubtypeOfIntegerNotIncluding10>`.  You want a `Box<Integer>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Short but informing. So thinking in this manner I can't put anything to A<?>?

Comment: You can add or set `null`, and you can get _out_ an `Object`, but you can't put anything but `null` in.

Answer (score 3):

The following  statement

```
Box<? extends Integer> box = new Box<Integer>();
```

means that box is **covariant**. And hence, you can take things out, but you can't put things in.

If you change it to the following

```
 Box<? super Integer> box = new Box<Integer>(); 
 box.set(10);
```

will work because it is **contravariant** now, you can put things in, but you can't take them out.

Say you have the following.

```
 class Box<T>{
    T t;
    void set(T t){
        this.t = t;
    }
    T get(){
        return t;
    }
 }
Box<? extends Integer> box1 = new Box<Integer>();
box1.set(10); // doesn't work
Integer i = box1.get(); // works
```

On the other hand

```
Box<? super Integer> box2 = new Box<Integer>();
box2.set(10); // works 
Integer i = box2.get(); // doesn't work
```

So you want to have both get/set, you can simply do this

```
Box<Integer> box = new Box<Integer>();
box2.set(10); // works 
Integer i = box2.get(); // works
```